I have applied a body background color using Tailwind, everything is up to date but my background is not changing in the website
This is my tailwins.config.js file below:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
import tailwindScrollbar from 'tailwind-scrollbar';

module.exports = {
  content: [
    "/index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{html,js, jsx}"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily:{
        'sans': ['Inter', 'sans-serif']
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [tailwindScrollbar],
};

This is the index.css file:
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


html{
    scroll-behavior:smooth;
}

body{
    @apply bg-amber-800 text-zinc-50;
} 

This is the App.jsx file:
import { StrictMode } from 'react'
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx';
import './index.css'

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
)


This is the index.html file:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="scrollbar-thin scrollbar-track-zinc-800 scrollbar-thumb-zinc-500">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Seemon's Portfolio</title>
    
    <link rel="shortcut-icon" href="/Images/favicon.svg" type="image/svg+xml"> 
   


    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" 
    crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Rounded:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@24,400,0..1,0" />


  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>


This is the main.jsx file:
import { StrictMode } from 'react'
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx';
import './index.css'

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
)


In the index.css file I was trying to change the background color but it is not appearing in the website. The text is showing but the color is not changing.


The Tailwind configuration file should be named tailwind.config.js, not tailwins.config.js.
Also, remove the space from inside the braces within the content file globs:
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "/index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx}"

